# Bash: For loop concatenates results instead of assigning individual lines;

Tags: bash, glob

This code parses a folder and if the folder contains multiple subfolders/files they are concatenated on ONE line with a space in between (subfolder1 subfolder2 subfolder3 /yo) instead of (subfolder1 /yo) newline (subfolder2 /yo) etc. I need one subfolder per line (it works as expected if there is only ONE subfolder in the directory).

Any suggestions?

```
FolderName=/yo
SUBDOMAINS=/data

for sourceX in "$SUBDOMAINS/*"
do
echo $sourceX $FolderName

done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glob char in `"$SUBDOMAINS/*"` must not be quoted:

```
"$SUBDOMAINS"/*
```

Better quote your arguments properly as well:

```
echo "$sourceX" "$FolderName"
```

Comment: That's it thanks, that was driving me nuts for a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the quotes around the globbing *. You want the quotes around the variable but not around the glob. You are telling the shell to make the glob expanded list of files into one string and then looping over that one string and printing it out.

You also probably want quotes around the variables in the echo line (though that's not related to this issue).